# I need clarification with some React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import Card from '../UI/Card';
import './Search.css';

const Search = React.memo(props => {
  const { onLoadIngredients } = props;
  const [enteredFilter, setEnteredFilter] = useState('');
  const inputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (enteredFilter === inputRef.current.value) {
        const query =
          enteredFilter.length === 0
            ? ''
            : `?orderBy="title"&equalTo="${enteredFilter}"`;
        fetch(
          'example-firebase-url.json' + query
        )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseData => {
            const loadedIngredients = [];
            for (const key in responseData) {
              loadedIngredients.push({
                id: key,
                title: responseData[key].title,
                amount: responseData[key].amount
              });
            }
            onLoadIngredients(loadedIngredients);
          });
      }
    }, 500);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [enteredFilter, onLoadIngredients, inputRef]);

  return (
    <section className="search">
      <Card>
        <div className="search-input">
          <label>Filter by Title</label>
          <input
            ref={inputRef}
            type="text"
            value={enteredFilter}
            onChange={event => setEnteredFilter(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </Card>
    </section>
  );
});

export default Search;
```

It uses a search bar so that when user is typing something his results gets filtered by making requests to a firebase server after that user stopped typing for 500 milliseconds.

The thing I don’t understand is that is mentioned that `enteredFilter` in `useEffect` is a closure so it's the value `setTimeout` locks, so it’s the old value and `inputRef` is the current value so it's compared the old value with the new one to see if the user stopped typing so the request can be made.
What I don’t understand is why `inputRef` is not a closure as well? Clearly it is used in the check statement inside the `setTimeout` function just like `enteredFilter` so shouldn t this value also be enclosed just like `enteredFilter`? It is mentioned that `inputRef` is not a closure because it’s defined outside of the closure, but as I see `enteredFilter` is also defined outside the closure and used inside just like `inputRef`.
Can someone help me understand this or the explanation is wrong?

Comment: It's inherent to the way `useRef()` works. It's not a closure, since React essentially creates a mutable object outside of the scope of the function[al component], which can act like an instance property. Essentially, you see the SAME ref from every render, rather than a closure over THAT render.

Comment: @osiris It also seems to have the same behavior without enteredFilter === inputRef.current.value, have you tried it? I'm actually not clear on why we need it. Tried to make a test if  enteredFilter !== inputRef.current.value will ever be triggered but I coudn't get it. So why do we need the checking for? I'm also following the same course :)

Comment: You need that check to compare if the value entered when you started typing it s the same after 500 milliseconds and if it is the case then you make a request because it means the user stopped typing . What I couldn t understand was why enteredFilter was considered a closure and not inputRef as well since they both behave similarly, they both survive rendering.

Answer (score 0):

input.current.value gives you the input after 500ms
enteredFilter give you the input before 500ms, and its connected to onChange this means its for change letter by letter at 500ms pass.